# Ruby on Rails: safely get the model class from a model_name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a polymorphic route that accepts the name of an ActiveRecord model (e.g. `"User"`, `"UserGroup"`) as a parameter.

How can I safely access the class based on the parameter?

The naive implementation (and likely not safe) would be:

```rb
model_class = params[:modelName].constantize
```

How can this be achieved without causing vulnerabilities?

Comment: Calling `constantize` on a user-supplied string is certainly something to do with caution, but is not - in and of itself - a security vulnerability. It depends what you *do next* with `model_class`.

Comment: Some points to consider: (1) Do you actually need to call `.constantize`?? (Why are you calling it?) (2) Do you trust your users? Are they random members of the public, or internal staff who do not really pose a security risk? (3) **Regardless** of any security concerns, you might want a more explicit handling of the parameter validity (instead of allowing literally any string) in order to *gracefully handle an error message* caused by bad input.

Answer (score 3):

I would use an explicit allowlist of models that the user is allowed to constantize in this context:

```
allowed_classes = ["User", "UserGroup"]
class_name = params[:modelName].presence_in(allowed_classes)

if class_name.present?
  model_class = class_name.safe_constantize 
else
  # handle error
end
```

[`presence_in`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-presence_in) returns the string if it is included in the array, `nil` otherwise.

Comment: Never knew about `presence_in` the rails team is very creative even if they do pollute the global landscape.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say that you would need a validation on that param, that checks if its value is in the collection of acceptable models, and after that, do indeed use `.constantize`.
If you accept all models, and all of them inherit from ApplicationRecord or something, you could generate the collection like this:

```rb
ApplicationRecord.subclasses.collect { |type| type.name }.sort
```

And check if params[:modelName] is in this collection.

Also take note that `constantize` does throw an error if no constant exists to match the result:

```rb
[1] pry(main)> "NotAConstant".constantize
NameError: uninitialized constant NotAConstant
```